# Why can not modify the value in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I have a `map` in `nginx.conf`,

```
stream {
    upstream s1{
        server 127.0.0.1:670;
    }
    upstream s2{
        server 127.0.0.1:680;
    }

    map $symbol_key $symbol_value{
        c1 s1;
        c2 s2;
    }
    server {
        set $symbol_key "c1";
        set $symbol_value "s1";
        listen 66;
        proxy_pass $symbol_value;
    }

}
```

If I delete `map`, the request can be routed to `s2` after I set `symbol_value` to `s2`. But I want to decide router throw `symbol_key`, if I use the `map`, no matter which value(`c1` or `c2`) I set to `symbol_key`, request
will always be routed to `s1`.

I modify the value in `phases[NGX_STREAM_PREREAD_PHASE].handlers` like this

```
ngx_str_t str1 = ngx_string("symbol_key");
ngx_uint_t key = ngx_hash_key(str1.data, str1.len);
ngx_stream_variable_value_t *vv = ngx_stream_get_variable(s, &str1, key);
ngx_str_t str2 = ngx_string("c2");
vv->data = str2.data;
vv->len = str2.len;
ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, c->log, 0, "after set");
```

Why can not the request be routed to `s2`?